# How to get remote client address in javax.websocket server?

Tags: java, jetty-9, java-websocket

I have a jetty 9.3.6 server that runs a websocket webapp. I would like to get the client IP address for bookeeping purposes, and I can see it is there in the `javax.websocket.Session` object, but I don't know how to get it as the API doesn't allow for it. Some folks seem to cast it to a `TyrusSession` object (from `org.glassfish.tyrus.core.TyrusSession`), but when I tried that, it compiled fine, but raised a `ClassCastException` in the websocket server at runtime. I have included the following in my  `build.gradle`:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.tyrus:tyrus-core:1.12'
```

What's the correct way to get the client IP address in a `javax.websocket.Session`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consistent with the [SO rules](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), I answer my own question here.

I got my clue when I tried to cast it to `TyrusSession` and Jetty complained (raised `ClassCastException`) in the error logs saying it was a `JsrSession` which cannot be cast into a `TyrusSession`. However, I had just printed the `Session` object in my logs, and something like this showed up:

```
session: WebSocketSession[....]
```

I then tried to cast it to `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession` which then complained about the object actually being a `JsrSession` which then led to my discovering the following solution:

```
@ServerEndpoint (value="/mySillyApp", configurator= ..., decoders={...})
public class MySillyWebSocketServer
{
    @OnOpen
    public void open (Session session, EndpointConfig config)
    {
        JsrSession jsrSession = (JsrSession) session; // import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.JsrSession;
        WebSocketSession webSocketSession = jsrSession.getWebSocketSession (); // import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.WebSocketSession;
        String clientIPAddressString = webSocketSession.getRemoteAddress ().getHostString ();
        ....
    }
    ...
}
```

Obviously, you will have to include the appropriate jars in your classpath. For gradle, you do this in the `dependencies {...}` section:

```
  compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:javax-websocket-client-impl:9.3.6.v20151106'
  compile 'org.eclipse.jetty.websocket:websocket-common:9.1.0.v20131115'
```

Hope my methodology and details helps someone.